# Http link - How to open a native application instead of a browser session

Tags: android, ios, facebook, mobile

I have the requirement to send a http/https link in an email.  Based on the device the link either needs to open up a web browser or a native application (if installed on the device).

My question is at a high level how would this be achieved?

I'm struggling to understand how you can do this from a web link?  If I look at facebook as an example on my android device my phone knows that it can either open the link using chrome or the native facebook app.

This happens before the browser opens so I'm guessing that you must implement some sort of listener on the native application that recognises certain domain names in http links and maps those to the native application?

I'm just after some high level information so I can understand the architecture of how this would be achieved.

Comment: You need to read this reference: [About Apple URL Schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: This seems to be information about opening other items from within a native application.  What I'm after is the inverse.  How to open the application from a link embedded in an email.  For example, "http://myappdomain.com/dosomething.aspx would open an ios app or android app if installed on the device that is reading the email.